# Hit mark won't disappear if player isn't hitting the enemy Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using `OnCollisionEnter` function to detect if bullet hit the enemy, ground, etc. When bullet hits the enemy, the hitmark should appear and disappear if bullet isn't hitting the enemy. It's just simple hit detector. But the problem is that it won't disappear after I done hitting the enemy. I have to shoot somewhere else to make it disappear. I figured that, that's how `OnCollisionEnter` function works. Is there any other way to code hitmark. Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
public Image hitMark;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision bullet){
    if(bullet.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")){
        Bot.curHealth -= 5;
        hitMark.enabled = true;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }else{
        hitMark.enabled = false;
    }
            
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by done hitting the enemy? if you can detect when you are done hitting, then set its activation to false there

Comment: When bullet is not detecting that it's hitting the enemy

Comment: Youre not making the sense you think you are. So. What is this code on?  If it was on an enemy then if the code was only on them then it wouldn't need to check what it was hitting. If its on the bullet its odd you call the collision bullet. But. You say in the question its not disappearing. That you have to hit something else to make it go. Well. Yes. Thats exactly what the code shown would do (depending on what the code is on) but also you say here in comments it doesnt detect its hitting an enemy.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already figured it out that there's nothing wrong in the code. My question is how to make it disappear immediately if enemy is not detecting collision from the bullet

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting `hitMark.enabled = false;` OnCollisionEnter. If no collisions occur, the enabled state will never change. This is why it only updates when you shoot another enemy, or if you shoot something else.

My solution would use a timeout to disable the hit marker. I'd remove the `else {}` section and add a coroutine timeout to the if statement

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision bullet){
    if(bullet.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")){
     Bot.curHealth -= 5;
     hitMark.enabled = true;
     Destroy(this.gameObject);
     StartCoroutine(HitMarkTimeout());
    }
}

IEnumerator HitMarkTimeout()
{
    for (int timeoutLength = 10; timeoutLength >= 0; timeoutLength--)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    hitMark.enabled = false;
}
```

This is just a starting point for a robust system. The timeout is based on frames, so your game will wait `timeoutLength` num frames until it disables the hitmaker. You might want to change this to `WaitForFixedUpdate`, so your players always see the hitmarker for a fixed num of seconds.

Also, you're gunna have a problem with this system because multiple 'hits' will start multiple `HitMarkTimeout()` coroutines. I'd increment a counter for each hit, and remove 1 in each HitMarkTimeout(). Then in your `Update()`, check for

```
hitMarkCount > 0 {
 hitMark.enabled = true;
} else {
 hitMark.enabled = false;
}
```

hitMarkCount can't exist on your GameObject as is because you destroy it on the first hit, so the state of the hitMarkCount would need to be held on another GameObject.

Comment: If you're looking for a system that updates as soon as the bullet leaves an enemy, you could probably just set `hitMark.enabled = false;` in `OnCollisionExit`